# Any performance difference between removeObject vs removeObjectAtIndex on a single object?

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa, nsmutablearray

Will `removeObjectAtIndex` be faster/more efficient in removing a single object from a `NSMutableArray` than `removeObject`?  I am assuming so since the search should be faster.

If a significant difference is to be expected for large arrays, I will keep track of the indices.  Hence, the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

To fill the gap, **all elements beyond index are moved by subtracting 1 from their index**.

```
- (void)removeObject:(ObjectType)anObject
```

This method uses `indexOfObject:` to locate matches and then removes them by using `removeObjectAtIndex:`. Thus, matches are determined on the basis of an object’s response to the `isEqual`: message. If the array does not contain anObject, the method has no effect (although it does incur the overhead of searching the contents).

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(ObjectType)anObject
```

Starting at index 0, each element of the array is sent an isEqual: message until a match is found or the end of the array is reached. This method passes the anObject parameter to each isEqual: message. Objects are considered equal if isEqual: (declared in the NSObject protocol) returns YES.

Case 1: Remove last object from array.

- removeObjectAtIndex will remove last object and no shifting is
  require so it will take O(1) time.
- removeObject will call    indexOfObject: this will take O(n) +
  removeObjectAtIndex will take    O(1) ~ O(n).

case 2:
remove first object from array.

- removeObjectAtIndex will remove first object and shift n-1 object.
  This will take O(n-1) ~ O(n).
- removeObject will call indexOfObject: this will take O(1) +
  removeObjectAtIndex will take O(n-1) ~ O(n).

Case 3 remove middle object from array

- removeObjectAtIndex will remove middle object and shift n/2 object.
  This will take O(n/2).
- removeObject will call indexOfObject: This will take O(n/2) +
  removeObjectAtIndex will take O(n/2) ~ O(n).

If you have index of object its better to call `removeObjectAtIndex:`

Answer (score 1):

`removeObjectAtIndex:` will be much faster (relatively speaking) than `removeObject:`.

`removeObjectAtIndex:` only deletes one object and at a specific and known index. This is O(1).

`removeObject:` must iterate the entire array and remove every instance of the object. And it must call `isEqual:` against every object in the array. This requires a lot more processing. This is O(n).

Having said all of that, whether it is actually a performance issue or not depends on the size of the array and what objects are in the array.

Don't worry about stuff like this unless you have a reason to suspect a performance issue and you use Instruments to see if there really is an issue.

Comment: Theoretically, `removeObjectAtIndex:` is O(1).  In implementation, it might require O(n) or O(log(n)) where n < numElements.  This is because the backing store may not be a C-style array.  Other than that, everything you've written about relative performance applies.

Comment: Apple should be publishing the Big-O notation for its collection classes, so the implementation is known...